# Google Script for Transferring Google Docs to SharePoint on a Regular Basis

Tags: sharepoint, google-apps-script

I have a feeling this is a long shot, but is there a Google script that can transfer everything in a Google site to SharePoint or a Google drive folder to SharePoint?

I would rather just use Google drive for collaboration as it is 100 times better than SharePoint (IMHO), but my company insists on using SharePoint. That being said, our team would like to continue using our Google site for collaboration and documentation which is why I am wondering if there is a script of some sort to transfer documents from Google to SharePoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this isn't an exact answer to my question. But this ended up making the process about 99% easier. I installed google drive locally so all of my files are placed in the google drive folder. I then opened sharepoint, and switched to explorer view. I then simply copied/pasted all the folders from google drive to the sharepoint folder, and about 30 seconds later all files were synchronized. It would be pretty simple to write a script to copy the files/folders from the google drive folder to the sharepoint folder. This was a simple way to solve an annoying problem, I hope this is helpful.